# How to import data from Excel using EPPlus to ASP.NET MVC, using C# and EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, epplus

I need to upload the information from an Excel xlsx file to my database through EF (Oracle), I use ASP.NET MVC and C#.

I tried to do this function but I don't know how to save the data in the database, I really don't know how to work with this tool is something totally new for.

What am I missing in my code to save the information? or if you know of any way to upload the information using the use of EPPlus that you can share.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateByFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    Entities db = new Entities();
    string path = "D:/Downloads/2023_Investment_Plan.xlsx";

    var list = new List<TB_PR_MST_PROJECT>();

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(path);

        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[4];
            var rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;

            using (Entities dc = new Entities())
            {
                for (int row = 4; row <= rowCount; row++)
                {
                    list.Add(new TB_PR_MST_PROJECT
                    {
                        PRJ_NAME = worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value.ToString().Trim(),
                        PRJ_TEAM_DETAIL = worksheet.Cells[row, 9].Value.ToString().Trim(),
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

Edit #1: Add Savechanges

```
                using (Entities dc = new Entities())
            {
                for (int row = 4; row <= rowCount; row++)
                {
                    list.Add(new TB_PR_MST_PROJECT
                    {
                        PRJ_NAME = worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value.ToString().Trim(),
                        PRJ_TEAM_DETAIL = worksheet.Cells[row, 9].Value.ToString().Trim(),
                    });
                }
                dc.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing a call to your DBContext, dc?,  to Add() and SaveChanges()

Comment: But how can I call the db context?

Comment: if "Entities" is your db context class ... you could use dc.Add() in the inner loop. Then after the loop, but still in that using block, call dc.SaveChanges().  All of this is a bit of guessing though, just based on what you're showing.

Comment: Added SaveChanges but not commit, the var list has 18 elements when for is execute but I dont know why it doesnt commit the results.

Comment: You're adding the entities to a temporary 'list' variable. You need to add them to the db context instead - `dc.Set<TB_PR_MST_PROJECT>().Add(...)`

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Yes its correct I use this code for my solution             using (Entities dc = new Entities())
            {
                foreach (var p in list)
                {
                    dc.TB_PR_MST_PROJECT.Add(p);
                    dc.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

Comment: That's important information. Can you please update your question to show all the relevant code in one place, instead of in two separate parts and in the comments